# Conveying 'Run test cases' (programming)

Tags: informatique, science, université

What is the most natural way to convey 'Run test cases' as in

> This document addresses functions, scripts, and basic good programming practices. It begins with some motivational examples and shows how to run test cases to check your solutions, making sure they are realistic. We conclude by discussing recursive and anonymous functions.

> Ce document traite des fonctions, des scripts et des bonnes pratiques de programmation de base. Il commence par quelques exemples motivants et montre comment exécuter des cas de test pour vérifier vos solutions, en s'assurant qu'elles sont réalistes. Nous terminons en abordant les fonctions récursives et anonymes.

Does 'exécuter des cas de test' sound idiomatic in this context ?

Comment: I think “cas de test” is a correct translation of “test case”, but I would use “run tests” in English, not “run test cases”. (I'm a professional developer and native French speaker, but I've only ever worked in multilingual teams where even French people speaking among themselves tend to use English words, so I don't know proper French terminology.)

Comment: Je comprends mal le contexte, peut-être [ceci](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8874834) ? cc @Gilles'SOnousesthostile'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

le terme *cas de test*, que ce soit un anglicisme ou non est couramment utilisé dans les équipes de développement.
Il désigne généralement le test d'un cas spécifique (cas nominal ou cas d'erreur), le test complet d'une fonctionnalité étant généralement composé de plusieurs cas de test.

S'agissant de la traduction de "Run the test cases", on utilise généralement les phrase suivantes :

- exécuter les tests / cas de test.
- jouer les tests / cas de test.
- dérouler les tests / cas de test.

Answer (score 2):

J'ai vu l'expression *cas test* (=test case) utilisé par mes collègues francophones; néanmoins ça me paraît comme un « anglicisme traduit ».

Je proposerais plutôt utiliser les expressions comme *effectuer un test*, *tester les solutions* ou même *faire les essais de solutions*, ou carrément *essayer vos solutions*.

Answer (score 1):

At my work we use the expression "exécuter des jeux de test". This might not be a perfect translation but this is the one we chose.

Comment: Selon moi, un *jeu de test* est une collection de *test cases*. Je le traduirais en anglais par *test set*.

Answer (score 1):

On pourrait écrire ceci :

> [...] et montre comment dérouler un ensemble de scénarios de test pour vérifier vos solutions.

<sub>Hors sujet: Plutôt que *motivants*, j'aurais peut-être choisi *incitatifs*.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

'cas de test' is not correct. Then, if the document is technical, there is nothing that forbids to use the original expression 'test case', keeping the quotation marks. It is also possible to translate 'run test case' with 'exécuter différents scenarios', or even 'valider vos solutions à travers différents scénarios'